# LibGDX Grid design

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I am coding a game similar to Plants vs Zombies which I would like to transfer from JFrame to LibGDX. The game functions, however I now have a problem with the grid. When I create a grid as below, the only thing that changes is the border colour and not the rectangle fill. Could someone inform me as to why this is happening? Also, if there is a more efficient means of superimposing a grid ?

```
 public Grid()
{
    db = new DB();
    ShapeRenderer sr = new ShapeRenderer();
    sr.setAutoShapeType(true);
    sr.begin();
    MainGame mg = new MainGame();
    for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {                
            sr.rect((float) (x * 145.45454545454545454545454545454545), (float) (y * 106.25), (float) 145.45454545454545454545454545454545, (float) 106.25);
            sr.setColor(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.BLACK);                
        }
    }
    sr.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ShapeType ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

**ShapeRenderer Reference:** https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html

Although, I'd prefer designing maps with a libGDX Tile maps, using a map editor like **Tiled Map Editor**. It's pretty flexible.

**libGDX Tile Maps:** https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps

**Tiled Map Editor:** http://www.mapeditor.org/